# How to merge MP4 files with different bitrates?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, mp4box, avidemux

I want to merge two or three MP4 videos with MPEG-4 AVC video codec and MP3 (sometimes MP3 Surround) audio codecs. Both audio and video can have different bitrate. If it will be possible, without transcoding. I already tried using FFmpeg, MP4Box and AviDemux, but with no success. I'm looking for a solution that can be executed using only command line.

Every movie is encoded by AviDemux with Two-Pass option.

#### There is how I tried to do it with AviDemux:

```
avidemux --force-alt-h264 --load video1.mp4 --append video2.mp4 --output-format MP4 --save output.mp4 --quit
```

#### There how with FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

#### And how with MP4Box:

```
MP4Box -cat video1.mp4 -cat video2.mp4 -new output.mp4
```

Sometimes it failed at all, but sometimes it gave me video with first file playing good, but the second file was corrupted.

`avprobe` command for the two files return this:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'ad.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    title           : ad.mp4
    encoder         : Lavf52.78.3
  Duration: 00:00:03.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 446 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 312 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25025 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16p, 126 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'ad-chipmunkove.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    title           : ad-chipmunkove.mp4
    encoder         : Lavf52.78.3
  Duration: 00:00:29.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2946 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2813 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25025 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16p, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

And FFmpeg merging this:

```
[concat @ 0xb03ae40] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, concat, from 'list.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 440 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 312 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25025 tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 126 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 312 kb/s, 25 fps, 25025 tbn, 25025 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 48000 Hz, stereo, 126 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  831 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10961kB time=00:00:33.23 bitrate=2702.0kbits/s
video:10414kB audio:518kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.266208%
```

The second part of the result video looks [this way](http://bordel.fisir.tk/merging.png), but audio is working fine.

Comment: How were the files generated? Exactly the same encoder and encoding settings just with a different bitrate? Or from different settings?

Comment: They're encoded with AviDemux. Same resolution, same FPS, others are same, too. Just different bitrate.

Comment: Generally it's possible if all other settings are the same, and if the sequences all start with an I-frame (or IDR-frame, to be more precise). I'm not sure about the MP3 part. MP3 is not supported in an MP4 container, I think.

Comment: @slhck MP3 [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14#Data_streams) supported, everything is working fine on every device I can imagine – Xbox 360, Android, Windows Phone and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating MP4 files, even with different bitrates, should work. That is the basic assumption of HTTP adaptive streaming using MPEG-DASH. If the decoder configuration is exactly the same, it is kept as is. If not exactly the same (but compatible), the sample description box `stsd` will have multiple entries.

For MP4Box, this looks like a bug. I suggest you file an issue [here](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues) with links to some example files.